# Factorisation over $\Bbb C$ of $z^2 -10z+30$

Tags: complex-numbers

I haven't done these questions in a long time, so I am just wondering if my approach and answer is correct.

When asked to $z^2-10z+30$ over $\Bbb C$,

My approach: I complete the square of the equation, and would get $(z-5+\sqrt 5)(z-5-\sqrt 5)$

My question/concern: I think that could be the answer, but I'm not sure if you have to include the "$i$" symbol to show that it's an imaginary factor.

If incorrect, please correct me.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: If you multiply out the factors you have, you get a constant term of $20$. You need $-5$ under your two radicals. Or, as you say, introduce $i$ as coefficients to those radicals.

Answer (score 5):

$z^{2}-10z+30=z^{2}-10z+25+5=(z-5)^2+5=(z-5)^{2}-(i\sqrt{5})^{2}=(z-5-i\sqrt{5})(z-5+i\sqrt{5})$. Edited:So you have to include the $i$ as $\sqrt{5}$ is real. Furhter, you can notice that the discriminant $(-10)^{2}-4(30)=-20<0$ so the solutions does have imaginary roots!

Comment: OHh, I knew I was missing something.

Comment: The solutions aren't imaginary, they are complex.

Answer (score 2):

The "$i$" should be included, thusly:

$z^2 - 10z + 30 = (z - 5 + i\sqrt{5})(z - 5 - i\sqrt{5}) ; \tag{1}$

without it, we have

$(z - 5 + \sqrt{5})(z -  5 - \sqrt{5}) = ((z - 5) + \sqrt{5})((z - 5) -\sqrt{5})$
$= (z - 5)^2 - (\sqrt {5})^2 = z^2 - 10z + 25 - 5$
$= z^2 - 10z + 20; \tag{2}$

on the other hand, with it:

$(z - 5 + i\sqrt{5})(z - 5 - i\sqrt{5}) = ((z - 5)+ i\sqrt{5})((z - 5) - i\sqrt{5})$
$= (z - 5)^2 - (i\sqrt{5})^2 = z^2 - 10z + 25 + 5$
$= z^2 - 10 z + 30, \tag{3}$

since $(i\sqrt{5})^2 = - 5$; in each of the above calculations we used the identity

$(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2; a, b \in \Bbb C.  \tag{4}$

To complete the square for $z^2 - 10z + 30$, we proceed as follows:

$z^2 - 10z + 30 = 0;\tag{5}$

subtract $30$:

$z^2 - 10z = -30; \tag{6}$

add $25 = (-10/2)^2$:

$z^2 - 10z + 25 = -5; \tag{7}$

then

$(z - 5)^2 = z^2 -10z + 25 = -5 = (i\sqrt{5})^2,  \tag{8}$

so

$(z - 5)^2 - (i\sqrt{5})^2 = 0, \tag{9}$

whence, *via* (4),

$((z - 5) + i\sqrt{5})((z - 5) - i\sqrt{5}) = 0; \tag{10}$

this shows the roots of $z^2 -10z + 30$ are $z - 5 \pm i\sqrt{5}$, so the factorization (1) binds.